# How to save as excel and vba project for future use?

Tags: vba, excel

How can I save as xlsx my project?
I try to do my project in excel with vba but I do know how to save it for future use.
If I save as excel sheet, vba will not be saved to it, I do know how to do that save.
Is there someone who has an idea to this problem?

Please anyone can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**xlsx** only for data sheet. When you have VBA code in your excel workbook you should save as **Excel Macro-Enabled workbook (*.xlsm)**

Answer (score 3):

Hello Schadrack Rurangwa**,

There a couple ways to do this.

**Altenative One:**

save the vba file to **"*.bas"***
1. Click on menu Tools->Macro->Visual Basic Editor
2. This will open Visual Basic Editor
3. In the visual basic editor, select menu File-> Rightclick somewhere in the module and select export file. (save your module ".bas" somewhere).

*Next time you start excel and want to use your VBA-Macro, just navigate to:

Tools>Macro->Visual Basic Editor> Rightlclick somewhere in the module and import the **"***.bas" file.*

**Altenative two:**
You could save the file Excelfile as **"*.xlsm"**
(A file with the XLSM file extension is an Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook file)

Answer (score 1):

Macros can be stored in individual workbooks or available for a user in all workbooks opened if they are stored in C:\Users\nnn\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART\ PERSONAL.XLSB.

For more info see https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-and-save-all-your-macros-in-a-single-workbook-66c97ab3-11c2-44db-b021-ae005a9bc790